# Is it not possible to make Apple Watch chime on the hour?

Tags: apple-watch, time

It's pretty common to have watches announce the beginning of a new time interval (say to beep every hour). Mac OS X allows users to have the system "announce the time" down to the quarter of hour.

Is there a way for Apple Watch users to do something similar?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87946/discussion-on-question-by-poige-is-it-not-possible-to-make-apple-watch-chime-on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure since which release (may be it was there at the time I asked this question) but there's built-in feature that chimes down to each quarter of hour — *not intuitively at all* you can find it under *Accessibility* (in Settings).

[image]

Comment: Since watchOS 6:  https://9to5mac.com/2019/10/04/hourly-chime-apple-watch/

Answer (score 8):

There's currently no native way to play a chime on the hour with watchOS - well, at least not without workarounds using the Timer, Reminders, etc.

However, there are a number of 3rd party Apple Watch apps available that provide this functionality. Below are just a few:

- [Little Ben](https://itunes.apple.com/app/little-ben-haptic-feedback/id1314858262#?platform=appleWatch)
- [Cuckoo Watch](https://itunes.apple.com/app/cuckoo-watch-hourly-chime/id984814911?l=en&mt=8)
- [Diii](https://itunes.apple.com/app/diii-notify-hourly-chime/id1001398032#?platform=appleWatch)

Comment: nice, what about ticking? :)

Comment: @poige One question per question is best policy. I'm going to edit that out of the main question so this can focus on the ability or inability to toll major hours and not tick by tock.

Comment: @bmike I've looked through a few of your own questions and easily found some where you're asking at least a couple of q-ns (sometimes even more). — Double standards…

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87972/room-for-poige-and-bmike

Comment: Feel free to propose an edit or raise that in [meta], @poige - same for my edit here. If you disagree with it [meta] is the perfect way to draw attention to it and get more eyes. No one is perfect and just because it's a "best policy" doesn't mean there can be exceptions and/or debate.

Comment: Oh, thank you. Feel free to rollback the edits you've done, @bmike due to no rules were saying I can't have two questions in single posting.